# Проверка синтаксиса rst-файла

Tags: python, github

У меня проблема с описанием (в формате [rst, reStructuredText](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText)) пакета на *pypi*.

`README.rst` прекрасно форматируется на [github](https://github.com/erm0l0v/python_wrap_cases/tree/0.1.3) и [readthedocs](http://python-wrap-cases.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) но в [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python_wrap_cases/0.1.3) *rst* не работает.

Есть ли способ решить эту проблему без копипаста `README` (в `README.md` например)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для проверки синтаксиса можно воспользоваться, например, программой `rst2html` (из пакета `python-docutils`). примерно так:

```
$ rst2html README.rst > /dev/null
README.rst:35: (WARNING/2) Literal block expected; none found.
README.rst:66: (WARNING/2) Literal block expected; none found.
README.rst:91: (WARNING/2) Literal block expected; none found.
README.rst:119: (WARNING/2) Literal block expected; none found.
README.rst:133: (WARNING/2) Literal block expected; none found.
README.rst:142: (WARNING/2) Literal block expected; none found.
```

из вывода видно, какие строки «не нравятся» парсеру.

насколько я понимаю, нужно лишь добавить по пробелу в начало этих строк (а потом ещё и в 134-й: про неё будет `warning` после исправления 133-й строки).

---

кстати, у этой программы есть и «основная» функция — генерация *html*:

```
$ rst2html README.rst > readme.html
```

после этого `readme.html` можно просмотреть в браузере.

---

в том же пакете есть ещё ряд полезных программ, начинающихся с `rst2` и делающих аналогичные преобразования в разные форматы:

```
rst2latex
rst2man
rst2odt
rst2odt_prepstyles
rst2pseudoxml
rst2s5
rst2xetex
rst2xml
```

и у каждой из этих программ есть множество опций. подробности смотрите, например, с помощью программы `man`:

```
$ man rst2html
```